# Was Bartholomew really a rebel?

Tags: blakes-7

In Season 3 Episode 8, "Rumours of Death", of the TV show *Blake's 7*, there are two subplots which advance in parallel:

- Avon is trying to get his hands on the person who killed his former lover, Anna Grant (introduced in concept in Season 2 Episode 9, "Countdown").
- Rebels on Earth are putting their plan into action to capture Servalan and bring down the Federation in her own presidential palace.

At the end of the episode,

> there's a shock reveal when the mysterious "Bartholomew" who sold out Avon years ago turns out to *be* Anna Grant, not her killer, and is also "Sula", Chesku's wife, who's leading the current rebellion against Servalan.

A reveal like this, which turns everything we thought we knew on its head, naturally leaves questions unanswered. It seems clear that

> Anna/Sula/Bartholomew really did betray Avon all those years ago, and didn't actually love him any more than she loved Chesku,

but how does this tie in with the events of the present day?

> Is she really rebelling now, genuinely trying to bring down the Federation by capturing Servalan? Or is it all another ploy like with Avon before, and she actually intended for Major Grenlee to get word out, or to keep Servalan alive until she could turn her coat again?

In other words,

> is she a Federation asset turned rebel, or 100% a Federation mole throughout?